# React Native: Can't find variable: require

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs, expo

I am trying to modify a [react native boilerplate](https://github.com/rayandrews/razzle-rnw-redux-loadable) so that I can be run on Android platform.

I installed the expo package and added an index.js file on the root directory. But when I run the android code, it raised `Can't find variable: require` on the bundling phase
[image]

I uploaded my code [here](https://github.com/michnath/rnw-ssr-multiplatforms). Does anyone have an idea what I missed here?

Answer (score 3):

resetting the cache worked for me.

On expo

> expo r -c

for pure react native

> react-native start --reset-cache

Answer (score 1):

For those whose cache clearing didn't work. Try **deleting .bablerc file**. It has its own ways of effecting cache. My issue was only resolved after i deleted this.
I came across this when i was porting my react native app to web using react-native-web .

Platforms:

expo
react native
react native web

Comment: For me the solution was to convert `babel.config.js` to a JSON file (`babel.config.json`).  I am not sure why, but any time I added `babel.config.js` it would raise the exception reported by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

reseting cache worked for me as well.

I use yarn.

```
yarn start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score -3):

You should import your server.default in es6 style. `require` is a `node.js` method, in es6 modules you should use `import` instead. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for more info on the usage of `import`.

Here you did

```
 const newApp = require('./server').default;
```

When you should have

```
import {default} from './server'
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with that, see issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21048

(we should be able to use require())