# Expo: Can't find variable require

Tags: react-native, expo

Dear stackoverflow community,

I'm not able to find any solution online for my problem. My error is the following:

```
Can't find variable: require

http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:5:24
global code@http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:701:3
```

[Screenshot Expo Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvrDL.jpg)

It was working perfectly 2 days ago, and (apparently) I didn't change anything since then.

Do you have any idea where it can come from?

I'm using:

- expo@~3.0.10
- react-native "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.0.tar.gz"

Very basic configuration. I'm suspecting some kind of miss configuration...

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Guillaume

**Updates 09-02-2020 4pm20:**

- I tried cleaning caches,
- I tried changing directory,
- I tried `expo init` a new app, importing the sources of the previous app, installing dependencies, it worked until I ran `expo start -c`, then the problem came back,
- Still working on it...

**Updates 09-02-2020 7pm:**

I finally succeed to make it work.

- Update expo-cli to the latest version
- Initialize a new expo app in another directory
- Copy/paste source code
- Use `expo start -c` instead of `expo start` to make sure no cache is involved in the following steps
- Install dependencies one by one to make sure none is the problem
- Finally test the app

Comment: have you try clearing the cache https://stackoverflow.com/a/54210259/11000016

Comment: I tried cleaning the cache. I tried to see if I have any require in the code. None of that.

Answer (score 1):

try by adding, import React from 'react' in the file where you mentioned require

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't have any...

Answer (score 0):

first : expo r -c ,
then : npm start,
finally: use require function